# Memory Issue in Javafx application

Tags: java, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks, javafx

I created a Javax application in netbean. I am facing the memory issue with it. I have a table witch contains the list of items that need to process and I am processing the tasks on item in mulitiple thread. as it process items one by one it increases system memory

**my finding with the above process**
Netbean - taking memory from ~130 to  300mb
Jar -  taking memory upto ~130 to 300mb
while I am running the build exe with same source code and run the application it takes 300m to 800mb/1100mb and so no
In the build exe we are passing the following parameter in settings....

```
<target name="CreatingExe" depends="SignedJar">
<fx:deploy width="800" height="600" nativeBundles="all" outdir="${dist}/winx86" outfile="${app.name}" verbose="true">
<fx:info title="${app.title}"/>
<fx:application name="${app.title}" mainClass="${main.class}"/>
<fx:resources>
<fx:fileset dir="${dist}/winx86" includes="*.jar"/>
<fx:fileset dir="${WorkingFolder}/temp"/>
</fx:resources>
<fx:platform>
<fx:jvmarg value="-Xms512m"/>
<fx:jvmarg value="-Xmx1g"/>
<fx:jvmarg value="-XX:NewRatio=2"/>
<fx:jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=250m"/>
</fx:platform>
</fx:deploy>
</target>
```

with this build exe, I bundled the  copy of jre (java 7)

what I need to add more setting for reducing the memory usages.

Comment: Do you actually get an OutOfMemoryError? Otherwise you might just see some memory usage increase because the garbage collection hasn't been run...

Comment: Yes. I am getting OutOfMemoryError. I have used System.gc() after the sort of situation. but evenafter it is increasing. 
I have two issiues...
1. Exe taking larger space then simple jar
2. Memory increase upto 1100+
So want to find out #1 first and then other...